# Google Analytics - Track file downloads without modify existing links

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I want to add to my site file downloads tracking with Google Analytics.

I understand that I need to add an 'onclick' event to all the links on the site.
Like this:

```
<a href="file.pdf" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Google Link', 'Action
label', 'Action Value');">link</a>
```

But I have so many links so it is not practical.

Is there a way to write any code in one place which will do the same thing?

Thanks.

Comment: you need to add a different label for links so you can recognize them. I don't think you can replace them in the same time and with the same label. for wordpress is something like this https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/ , maybe you can replicate that pluggin functionality.

Comment: @DincaAdrian - My site is not a wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, is to define a global event tracking, you need to be extremely careful with target="_blank" target="_self" or with event.preventdefault() on events,

Here is how you can do it, attaching event for all links having in href specified file extensions:

```js
console.clear();
(function ($) {
    var filesExtensions = ['.pdf', '.docx', '.xsls', '.jpg'];
    //attach event for each file
    filesExtensions.forEach(function (element) {
        //http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/
        //why mouse down? becouse a link can have target _blank or some other preventdefault or stopPropagation on click event defined
        //you can use click, but you might face some problems
        $("a[href$='" + element + "']").mousedown(function (event) {
            pushDownload(event.target);
        });
        //prevent event propagation (stack overflow will show ugly server error at link navigation)
        //this click event is not part of implemntation
        //TODO: remove on your website
        $("a[href$='" + element + "']").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });

    function pushDownload(target) {
        var eventCategory = "Files";
        var eventAction = "Download";
        var eventLabel = getFileName($(target).attr('href'));
        console.log("ga('send', 'event', '" + eventCategory + "', '" + eventAction + "','" + eventLabel + '");');
        if (window.ga && ga.loaded) {
            ga('send', 'event', eventCategory, eventAction, eventLabel);
        }
        else {
            console.error("Exception: ga undefined");
        }
    };

    function getFileName(str) {
        return str.substr(str.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="file.pdf">file.pdf download</a><br>
<a href="file.docx">file.docx download</a><br>
<a href="/invoices/invoice.pdf">invoice.pdf download</a>
```

Comment: It looks interesting.
Does it only work with version 2.1.1 of jquery? My site uses an earlier version...

Comment: attributeEndsWith selector added in jquery 1.0, so you are covered

Comment: OK. I was asked to look into this issue,
It will take some time until the customer decides to do it...
When I'll do it - I'll try to implement your answer and I will continue to update. Thank you!